# Selenium multiprocess python3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have list of 42000 elements that I need to pass in a function one by one that fetches data from the site one at a time which is taking too long just for even 100 elements. so is there any way I can make it fast. the main problem is for every element driver opens and returns the data so by my code it has to open and close for 42000 times to get the data.

**here's the list :**

```
zip_codes = ["00520", "43224", ..42000 zip codes]
```

**here's my function which is getting the data :**

```
article = []
def zipread(zipcode):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe') 
        driver.get("https://apps.pnc.com/locator/search")
        search = driver.find_element_by_id("extTxtSearchText")
        search.send_keys(zipcode) 
        search.click()
        search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(7)

        a = driver.find_element_by_class_name("branch-address").text
        articles.append(a)


 for code in zip_code:
    zipread(code)
```

this is the work happens for each zip. so what should I do to make it quick.

Comment: Try using multiprocessing **and a headless browser**

Comment: Also, selenium should always be used as a last resort. Are you sure this can't be achieved by plain HTTP requests?

Answer (score 0):

So, you enter in the world of multiprocess, and multithreading ! It's not that hard you just need to get used to it I see two solutions for your problem idk which one is the best but I have my idea, the easiest one:

Try with bash !

Your python programm will take 1 zip code in argument ! And you will call your programm the number of time you want , `python3 your_programm.py [zip_code]` (for example ), but you will call it from a bash script.

You can program in bash, (scripting language) but you can code so you can something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
zip_codes=("00520" "10000" ... "42000")
for i in ${!zip_codes[@]};
do
  log=${logPaths[$i]}
  python3 you_program.py log &
done
```

the "&" means forground process, so each time it your programm is calles he won't wait the end of the previous end, and so on!
I'm not 100 percent sure about the code but you know what I mean !

The other options will be to use multiprocess, in python look at [this](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/multiprocessing-in-python) you can basically do the same logic as the bash thing, you call a process for each time you want to run your program!

HUGE TIPS: run selenium in headless mode it's really important in terms of performance

GL